# Intellj package prefix is reset by gradle refresh of projects

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-13

I am using intellij 13.  I have set package prefix in the "Project Structure" window.

[image]

Everything works fine until I add a new dependency or even just refresh the gradle dependencies. At that point Intellij resets all the project prefixes to be ""  and from then on all the imports etc for my project are broken until I go back into the Project Structure settings and re-enter the prefix.

Is there some setting in the gradle files I need or some other way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: From a cursory glance at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/content-root.html#package_prefix, this would mean that `com.example.SomeClass` would end up directly in `src/test/java`.  That would directly conflict with Gradle's expectations, so it's rightly resetting things when you refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this customization of a generated IntelliJ project but you can add it to your build scripts if you create `idea.module.iml.withXml` hook where you can update generated XML for your module. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html and linked docs for more details. This can make it work for projects generated using `gradle idea` task. The project import/refresh from in the IJ may ignore this.

Of course updating your directory structure is the simplest solution. Unless you have a good reason to keep that special layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I stopped trying to use the Intellij short cut and created the whole file structure for the package.

It turns out that Intellij hides most of the empty folders any way, so there is only one folder on display rather than a large folder tree.